# MenuItem multiple parent

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, selection, menuitem, multipleselection

I have a menu item that appears when right clicking over a datagridview. From their the user hovers over a menuitem and a list of other menu items appears, once again this repeats. Giving soemthing like this.

```
---------
|  FOO  |---------
---------|  BAR  |------------
          ---------|  FOOBAR  |
                   ------------
```

There is only to be an event (addressof) handled on the the 3rd tier. With that being said I need to grab the parent.name from FOOBAR and the parent.name of the said parent (grandparent).

Here is where I am at:

```
If currentMouseRow >= 0 AndAlso currentMouseColumn <= 1 Then
            dataGridView_monitorMapping.Rows(currentMouseRow).Selected = True
            mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(New MenuItem("Set Monitor(s) Settings"))
            mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(New MenuItem("Sync Monitor Mapping View", AddressOf triggerSync))
            'list avaliable priorites
            For Each priorityRow As DataRow In priorityTypesDS.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim rowPriortiyName As String = CStr(priorityRow("Priority"))
                Dim subMenu_priorities_item As New MenuItem(rowPriortiyName)
                mainMenu.MenuItems(0).MenuItems.Add(subMenu_priorities_item)
                'list avaliable boards
                For Each boardRow As DataRow In serviceBoardDS.Tables(0).Rows
                    Dim rowBoardName As String = CStr(boardRow("SvcBrd"))
                    Dim subMenu_boards_item As New MenuItem(rowBoardName)
                    subMenu_priorities_item.MenuItems.Add(subMenu_boards_item)
                    'list avaliable types based on board
                    If rowBoardName IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim availableSvcTypes As DataSet = GetServiceTypes(_objhost, serviceTypes, rowBoardName)
                        For Each svcTypeRow As DataRow In availableSvcTypes.Tables(0).Rows
                            Dim rowSvcTypeName As String = CStr(svcTypeRow(1))
                            Dim subMenu_svcType_item As New MenuItem(rowSvcTypeName, AddressOf triggerSync)
                            subMenu_boards_item.MenuItems.Add(subMenu_svcType_item)
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            mainMenu.Show(dataGridView_monitorMapping, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        End If
```

And the event handler

```
Public Sub updateMultiRowSettingChange(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'TODO | Handle selection from right click menu.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you what you are looking for:

```
Public Sub updateMultiRowSettingChange(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim item As MenuItem = CType(sender, MenuItem)
    Dim parent As MenuItem = CType(item.Parent, MenuItem)
    Dim grandparent As Menu = parent.Parent
End Sub
```

However, it may be simpler to set the tag on the menu item to whatever information you need to know where it's coming from, then you could just check `item.Tag` after you cast it to the MenuItem class.